# End user session when on new browser tab

Tags: javascript, java, dom-events

We have a financial application in which when a user opens a link in a new tab and closes  the previous one his session is still active in the new tab. This can create issues of Cross Site Request Forgery  which , to us, is a big issue. Talking to our developers about this in implementing something that uses onload or unload (as described here http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/2948770) said that the way the application is build (Java+faces+jboss+tomact) will create issues as the use will be logged out each time he clicks on a menu. This is because the function is called whenever a user navigates from one page to another.

Is there a way around this issue without using the unload/onload Javascript function?

Comment: may i know how opening link in new tab will cause CSRF?

Comment: http://mehmoodbluffs.blogspot.com/2007/10/detecting-browser-event-closing-in.html

Comment: @Suresh check this out (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) if the user does not click on logout and just simply closes the tab  (not the browser)without logging out, his session is still active and can possibly be hijackd. this does still pose a risk for the client and the financial institution

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to detect the user closing the page without using javascript.

However, it would be more user-friendly if you stored multiple CSRF tokens instead of just a single one (e.g. up to 10). When one is used, only this one is invalidated and when a new one is necessary, the oldest one is deleted.
This ensures people can work in multiple tabs while still having CSRF protection.

Comment: hmmm we dont currently use CSRF tokens

Comment: wouldn't this cause issues with the back button?